# Delete all reoccurrences of first line in a file using sed

Tags: file, unix, sed, find, line

I've got a bunch of files with multiple rows containing copies of the header. Is there a way using sed to delete all occurrences except for the first line. I was thinking something like:

`sed -i '/textOnlyInHeader/d' file.txt`

Except this will delete the header as well. As a bonus, is there a way to do this recursively for all files in a bunch of subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `gawk` would be best for this. Try:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==1 { r = $0; print } r == $0 { next }1' file.txt
```

For all files in a single directory, change `NR` to `FNR` and run:

```
gawk -i inplace '...' *.txt
```

For all files in many subdirectories, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for i in $(find /path/to/files -type f -name '*.txt'); do ... ; done
```

---

If you're using an old or non-GNU AWK, you will need to write to a temp file first:

```
awk '...' file.txt > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: Using `FNR` would be more apt since OP is planning to use it against multiple files (and plans to use it against file glob)

Comment: That is true only when multiple arguments are specified. If the OP chooses to glob, then I agree, `FNR` would be a better choice. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1b;G;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '1 !{
   /textOnlyInHeader/ d
   }' file.txt
```

avoid first line and use your sed on other line

for the recursive, you could passe to sed a list of file (in place of just file.txt). So prepare the list before with a shell function (find, ls, ..., loop) an pass it to the sed as argument

Answer (score -1):

I know there's already an accepted answer using `gawk`, but using `sed`:

```
sed -i -e '2,$s/textOnlyInHeader/DELETELINE/' -e '/DELETELINE/d' file.txt
```

for the recursive answer, I concur with Steve that a loop with `find` is the way to go.

Comment: -1 Need to "Delete all reoccurrences of first line in a file using sed"